# ver el am o pm de un datetime en c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Un saludo a todos, estoy haciendo un sistema de registro de asistencia y al registrar la entrada y salida de un profesor me guarda la fecha, pero la AM o PM este es mi código:

```
public void registrarasistencia()
{
   string fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
   objent.fechahora = fecha;           
}
```

He visto muchos códigos indicándome que el tt es obtener el am o pm pero no logro obtener , GRACIAS A TODOS.

Comment: No termino de entender tu problema...

Comment: @gbianchi , quiero obtener el AM o PM de un datetime para al guardar una asistencia al hacer un reporte me muestre con el AM o PM , al traer el reporte solo me trae la fecha y la hora pero omite el AM , PM

Comment: Pero en ese caso, el problema es el reporte.. la fecha se guarda como fecha, que no se muestre algo es problema de quien lo muestra...

Comment: Donde estas haciendo el reporte, y por otra parte revisa tu redaccion que esta mal

Comment: ¿Qué tal si lugar de depender de la cultura por defecto, verificas si la hora es mayor o igual a 12? `DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12`. Si es menor es AM, sino PM.

Answer (score 1):

el indicador para cadena corta (AM/PM) es "t". Y para mostrar el AM/PM debes setear el Cultureinfo a "en-us".

Aqui un ejemplo

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2022, 4, 10, 9, 45, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("t",
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")));
// Muestra 9:45 AM
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("t",
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES")));
// Muestra 9:45
```

Te invito a revisar la documentación [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#ShortTime)

**EDIT**
Tal como comenta Mateo aquí debajo, te dejo la documentación de

```
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
```

[En este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0)

Comment: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` sería una mejor opción.

Comment: @Mateo gracias por el aporte, edito la respuesta con la documentación correspondiente a dicha propiedad